# How to load settings from a folder

Tags: python, django

I have my settings defined like below

```
app
  |- settings.py
  |- settings_local
    |- set1.py
  |- ..
```

in `manage.py`

```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
     os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings_local.set1.py")
```

This is not working. How can I do it. I would like to refer settings to `set1.py`

Comment: Where is manage.py located? In this tree.

Comment: @dt0xff It is beside app folder.

Comment: I bet your settings_local folder has no `__init__.py` file or you have run manage.py from different folder. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, your `settings_local` folder has no `__init__.py` file, which should be here to make python know that it is python package.

Also, like @qfiard pointed out, you should not write `.py` in this string, because it is `import path`, not file path.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a Python package does not include the `.py` extension. Try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings_local.set1")
```

Comment: It is raising an error `(Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named : app.settings_local.set1`. Thanks for the reply.